# TypedQuery cannot proceed with boolean in where block

Tags: java, boolean, hql

I've got entity AnnouncementEntity in my code:

```
public class AnnouncementEntity {

    //columns
    private long id;    
    ***
    private Boolean on;
    ***
    @Column(name="ACTIVE")
    public Boolean getOn() {
        return on;
    }

    public void setOn(Boolean on) {
        this.on = on;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get all records which have 'true' in this field:

```
TypedQuery<AnnouncementEntity> query = 
em.createQuery("select p from AnnouncementEntity p where p.on = TRUE",       AnnouncementEntity.class);
```

But I faced with exception :

`SEVERE: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: p near line 1, column 60 [select p from com.ui4ivr.entity.AnnouncementEntity p where p.on = TRUE]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1679)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:313)
    at com.ui4ivr.dao.daoImpl.getAllAnnsVShort(daoImpl.java:933)
    at com.ui4ivr.view.MainView.enter(MainView.java:259)`

Could you please say what is wrong?

Comment: The real cause was incorrect mapping to field.

Comment: The filed should has the same name as the real column in db.
I've substituted "Boolean active;" for "Boolean on;"
<property name="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 1, false 0</property>

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you have defined your `ACTIVE` column, you should map your property accordingly:

- `org.hibernate.type.BooleanType` Maps a boolean to a JDBC BIT type
- `org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType` Maps a boolean to a JDBC
  INTEGER type as 0 = false, 1 = true
- `org.hibernate.type.YesNoType` Maps a boolean to a JDBC CHAR type as
  ('N' | 'n') = false, ( 'Y' | 'y' ) = true
- `org.hibernate.type.TrueFalseType` Maps a boolean to a JDBC CHAR type
  as ('F' | 'f') = false, ( 'T' | 't' ) = true

For example, if your `ACTIVE` column is a CHAR(1) and stores 'Y' or 'N' values, you should define the related method in your entity as:

```
//columns
private long id;    

@Type(type="yes_no")
@Column(name="ACTIVE")
private Boolean on;

public Boolean getOn() {
    return on;
}

public void setOn(Boolean on) {
    this.on = on;
}
```

Also, change your query:

```
TypedQuery<AnnouncementEntity> query = 
em.createQuery("select p from AnnouncementEntity p where p.on is TRUE", AnnouncementEntity.class);
```

Comment: Your comment helped me ti find a real cause. Em query can work with number(1) only.  However it worked good without 'where' block